# How to set default for a c-string in c++ class?

Tags: c++, class, char, c-strings

Here is my default constructor for a class called Blackjack:

```
Blackjack::Blackjack(char *names[], int numPlayers)
:m_names('jane'),m_numPlayers(numPlayers)
```

in the "Private:" I have "char m_names;"
to give it a default value, what would i name it under the constructor?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense at the moment. A `char` isn't a C string.

Comment: Show how do you declare class `Blackjack`

Comment: I strongly suggest you take and store the player names as a `std::vector<std::string>` - it'll make your code massive simpler and be less error prone.  You won't need `numPlayers` as you can use `std::vector::size()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot actually use a default parameter for names before you use one for numPlayers, which is all to the good.

Define an external char const * const* in the same header before the constructor, and use that name as default. Take a corresponding int constant for numPlayers...

Don't forget to define your constant in your cpp file.

Aside: I'm counting on you to add the needed const qualifiers to names